# Is there a way to pass a useState array to another component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm creating a video game shopping cart.

I have a component that is storing data of recent video games.

**VideoGameList.js**

```
const VideoGameList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Fire Emblem Engage",
    inCart: false,
  },
];
```

And another component that displays the objects in their own div. Inside that component I have this code which takes the VideoGameList array and sets a new array upon clicking *"Add to Cart"* and changes the `inCart` value from `false` to `true`.

**VideoGame.js**

```
const [cart, setCart] = useState(VideoGameList);

  const handleCartStatus = (id) =>
    setCart(
      cart.map((value) =>
        value.id !== id ? value : { ...value, inCart: !value.inCart }
      )
    );
```

I then have to map through the new array like so

```
{cart.map(
          ({ id, title, inCart }, index) => (
            <div>
              <img key={src} src={src} alt={title} />
              <div>
                <p>{title}</p>
                <p>{releaseDate}</p>
              </div>
              <div>
                <p>${price}</p>
                <button
                  onClick={() => handleCartStatus(id)}
                >
                  Add to Cart
                </button>
```

**Here's my problem**

I have a third component which is the actual ShoppingCart page. Originally when I made this component I was using this code

**ShoppingCart.js**

```
const ShoppingCart = () => {
  return (
    <>
      <Header />
      {VideoGameList.some((v) => v.inCart) ? (
        <div>
          {VideoGameList.filter((v) => v.inCart).map(
            (
              { id, title, inCart },
              index
            ) => (
              <div>
                <img key={src} src={src} alt={title} />
                <div>
                  <p>{title}</p>
                  <p>{releaseDate}</p>
                </div>
                <div>
                  <p>${price}</p>
                  <button>Add to Cart</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            )
          )}
        </div>
      ) : (
        <div>
          <h1>Your Shopping Cart Is Empty!</h1>;
          <div className="shopping-cart-image">
          </div>
        </div>
      )}
    </>
  );
};
```

The code works in one of two ways. Either the user has an empty shopping cart and an image + some text is displayed or they have a minimum of one item in their shopping cart and a div of said item (video game) was displayed. An item is considered in their shopping cart when the `inCart` value is set to true. I was basing the `some` and `filter` methods on the `VideoGameList` array and was manually changing the `inCart` values to true to see if it worked (it did) however, because I have to change state from the `VideoGame` component I have to change `VideoGameList.some` and `VideoGameList.filter` to `cart.some` and `cart.filter` to get the updated `inCart` values but every time I change it I get this error.

```
src\Components\ShoppingCart.js
  Line 11:8:   'cart' is not defined  no-undef
  Line 13:12:  'cart' is not defined  no-undef
```

If I continue using VideoGameList it will never update the Shopping Cart but I can't find a way to use cart from my VideoGame component inside my ShoppingCart component. Please advice.

Comment: I can't make out what the actual problem is, but for what it's worth and in case it's helpful, the answer to the question in the title is "of course," you can pass an array held in state to a child component  just like you can pass anything else held in state to a child component: `<TheChildComponent theArrayProp={theArray} />`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you for the response. I've tried that in both my `App.js` and `index.js` file. `<VideoGame cart={cart}` and then used `props.cart.some` in my `ShoppingCart` component but for some reason it wasn't working.

Comment: You said you've passed it to `VideoGame` but then you said you tried to use it in `ShoppingCart`. You'd have to pass it to `ShoppingCart`. Please update your question with a **runnable** [mcve] demonstrating the problem using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). With an MRE we should be able to help you.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thank you again for the response. I tried adding the MRE but I kept getting errors. What I'm trying to do is figure out how I can use `cart.some` and `cart.filter` inside my `ShoppingCart` component, when my `cart` is inside the `VideoGame` component. I've tried putting `ShoppingCart cart={cart}` inside my `VideoGame` component but it was duplicating my code. I know I'm close I just can't figure it out.